# Splitting URL with parameters into separate strings

Tags: c#, enumeration

My working data is a list of type string:

```
    a.aspx?a=1
    a.aspx?a=2
    a.aspx?a=3
    b.aspx?b=1
    b.aspx?b=2
    b.aspx?b=3
    c.aspx?c=1
    c.aspx?c=2
    c.aspx?c=3
```

What i'd like to do is:

1. take the first value in the list (a.aspx?a=1)
2. get the pagename (a.aspx)
3. place all the matching pages into a separate collection (a.aspx?a=1,2,3)
4. remove all the entries in the original list that match the pagename (a.aspx)
5. Repeat 1-4, this time the first entry will be b.aspx
6. So on until i have separate collections for each page name

I can do 1-3 alright but i'm not sure the best way to do step 4 & 5 namely dynamically creating the collections from within a loop or some alternative that achieves a similar result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show what code you have so far for getting 1-3 so it can be improved upon.

Comment: Yes, I have a suggestion: Make an attempt, and see how far you get on your own. When you get stuck, and have a more specific question, post it here, and I'm sure there will be lots of people willing to help you. As your current question stands, it is a little broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So  you want to `GroupBy` page name and build sub-lists for every page? Then this should work:

```
List<List<string>> urlsPerName = list
    .Select(u => new { Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(u), Full = u })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Full).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Result, three lists with three strings each:

```
        [0] "a.aspx?a=1"    string
        [1] "a.aspx?a=2"    string
        [2] "a.aspx?a=3"    string

        [0] "b.aspx?b=1"    string
        [1] "b.aspx?b=2"    string
        [2] "b.aspx?b=3"    string

        [0] "c.aspx?c=1"    string
        [1] "c.aspx?c=2"    string
        [2] "c.aspx?c=3"    string
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could explain how the linq query works, or point me towards some material that might help me better understand it?

Comment: @Solaris: What exactly don't you understand? [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx) groups elements of a sequence lazily. So the `Select` returns anynonymous types with two properties. The `GroupBy` groups them by the `Name` property(so the part before the period) which returns three groups. Then the `Select` projects these groups, the _inner_ `Select` projects again the anonymous type, the `ToList` creates a collection from the `Full` property(original string). The outer `ToList` creates a `List<List<string>>`.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get a feel of what it did by stepping through it in debug but I wanted to be sure I was following it.